# Javascript unexpected identifier?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a function which takes the average of all the elements in an array. However, I am getting an unexpected identifier error.

```
function calculateAverage(anyArray) {
    var sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < anyArray.length; i++) {
        sum += anyArray[i];
    }
    sum = sum / anyArray.length;
}
```

I have counted my braces and parentheses and the error seems to be happening only when the for loop is included, as when I removed it the error does not occur.

Comment: `int` isn't valid in javascript. Use `var` or `let`

Comment: You need to say which identifier it is complaining about. My guess is the `int i`. Because that isn't Javascript. It's C++.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `for` loop, you are using `int`, which is not a keyword in javascript, hence the error "Unexpected identifier". You should use `var`, or `let`.